# "variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)" error when using a variable from method declaration in method block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a small iOs application which retrieves information from a server, and I found the pretty useful NSURLSessionDataTask.
First I used a `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectArray;`
which I called in my method:

```
    - (void) createObjectsArrayFromUrl: (NSString *) url {
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error) {
                                      //error handling
                                  }
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                     NSMutableDictionary *jsonDataDictionary = [objectModel getJsonData];

                    self.objectArray = [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];

                                      [[self collectionView] reloadData];

                                  });
                              }];
[task resume];
}
```

And it all went smooth.
Now I want to create a universal method, for more arrays, and I thought to do it  by passing the array to the method, and updating it inside, like this:

```
- (void) createObjectsArrayFromUrl: (NSString *) url inArray: (NSMutableArray *) objectArray{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      if(error) {
                                          //error handling
                                      }
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                         NSMutableDictionary *jsonDataDictionary = [objectModel getJsonData];

                        objectArray = [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];

                                          [[self collectionView] reloadData];

                                      });
                                  }];
    [task resume];
    }
```

but it gives me the error in the title in the following line: `objectArray = [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];` and I don't know how to proceed.
So my idea is, instead of creating a method for every array I have, like before, I want to pass the array as a variable and update it in the method. 
How to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: instead of assigning objectArray to [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];, try [objecyArray removeAllObjects], [objectArray addObjectsFromArray:[objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary]];

Comment: Thanks, it works now!
Care to give a little explanation? I'm a newbie in the Obj-C world!

Comment: added as answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
objectArray = [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];
```

try

```
[objecyArray removeAllObjects];
[objectArray addObjectsFromArray:[objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary]];
```

This is because the variable coming in does not have `__block` in front of it thus allowing it to be used in a block, this is only available for local variables and not parameters. I believe `__block` does so under the hood stuff to allowing to be referenced inside a block.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to access variable in block then you should assign it as block first like `__block NSArray *arr;`. then you can access that variable in block means in your completion handler.

In your code you can add one line at start of the method body like,

```
__block NSArray *arr =  objectArray;
```

And then use this `arr` in block like,

```
 arr = [objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary];
```

Hope this will help :)