# Passing an NSArray from Swift into Objective-C function

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray, block

I am calling a function from an Objective-C class. I passing an array from my Swift class into an Objective-C function.

Here is my code for the Swift

```
var videosAutoCompletion:[String] = []

completeSearch.autocompleteSegesstions(searchText, self.tableView, self.videosAutoCompletion)
```

Objective-C Function

```
 -(void)autocompleteSegesstions : (NSString *)searchWish :(UITableView*)table :(NSArray*)stringArray
```

Inside the Objective-C function i had a block

```
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.ParsingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array that contains the objects.
        for (int i=0; i != [jsonObject count]; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j != 1; j++) {
                //NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonObject objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j]);
                [self.ParsingArray addObject:[[jsonObject objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j]];
                //Parse the JSON here...
                //NSLog(@"Parsing Array - %@",self.ParsingArray);

                stringArray =  [self.ParsingArray copy];
                [table reloadData];

            }
    }

    });
```

I am getting this error for the following line.

> Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)
>   at line

```
 stringArray =  [self.ParsingArray copy];
```

Comment: There are at least two StackOverflow questions that address this error. It doesn't have to do with Swift; it has to do with using a "block" (Objective-C name for a "closure" in Swift). [Assign a variable inside a Block to a variable outside a Block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7962721/1107226) and [“variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)” error when using a variable from method declaration in method block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573957/1107226)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify the value of the `stringArray` function parameter within a block, so you should tell that to the compiler. You could try making a copy right before the `dispatch_sync` call as such:

```
    __block NSArray *stringArrayCopy = [stringArray copy];
```

and use the copy within the block.

This will silence the compiler errors, but please note that if your intention is to change your Swift `videosAutoCompletion` array by setting the `stringArray` parameter within the ObjC method, you need to change your approach. Setting `stringArray = [self.ParsingArray copy];` only has an effect local to the 
`autocompleteSegesstions:::`
function.